# Cannot access website through company LAN network

Tags: web, dns, lan, cname

I have setup a subdomain as 'gallery' for my website, which is eastwest.org.  We are using Big Cartel as an ecommerce store, so in order to point to gallery.eastwest.org, I've created the CNAME with Alias as 'gallery' and Host Name as 'ewministries.bigcartel.com.'

I'm remote and outside the company network, so I can see the site just fine.  However, employees inside of our office network, cannot reach the page before it times out.

Any thoughts on how to get this to work inside the company too?  I'm sure I'm missing some simple DNS change.

Thanks!
Chelsea

Comment: run `ping gallery.eastwest.org` and `traceroute gallery.eastwest.org` commands from a computer inside your LAN. and post the output here. Also, check if you use a local DNS server (internal to your lan).

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure what the web address you are checking is but try this:

From a computer within your company network:

- Open command prompt
- type: nslookup
- type: set type=all
- type: `the address of the website`
- Post the result